# Exposing a dependency with a gradle build

Tags: java, maven, gradle, dependencies

My product is using a third party dependency called matlab control version 4.1.0. This jar file allow java to send command to matlab.

The way we use it is by calling a java command in matlab (triggered by the user), this perform a bunch of computation in the java plugin, then java sends a notification to matlab which then start executing m code with data received from java.

So far, the jar file is stored in our repository, and directly loaded in matlab.

We want to move to matlab-control v5.0.0, which is on maven. So we thought it was the occasion to get rid of the jar file, include it as a dependency from maven in our gradle build.

However the api seems to not be visible to Matlab, which returns an exception 'can not find class org.n52.matlabcontrol.MatlabProxy'.

If I test the connection directly from java (by creating a java test), java will by itself launch matlab and request the command to be executed (for instance, an hello world command). It's working fine, and I can then instantiate a MatlabProxy. But if I launch Matlab and try to access the MatlabProxy directly from it, it cannot find it.

So it seems that the Matlab-control API is not exposed by my gradle build. So far I have tried the following:

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'

dependencies {
    implementation('org.n52.matlab:matlab-control:5.0.0')
    api('org.n52.matlab:matlab-control:5.0.0')
}
```

But it is not working, so what I am missing ?

Comment: First don't use both implementation and api. What changed in your `build.gradle` between 4.1.0 and 5.0.0 version ?

Comment: In 4.1.0 the jar file was on my disk, referenced to gradle using compile FileTree, and then directly added to matlab using javaaddpath. In 5.0.0 gradle retrieve the jar from maven so there's no jar file to add into matlab.

Comment: *so there's no jar file to add into matlab*: why? If matlab needs a jar file, it needs a jar file. Whether the jar file comes from your local disk or from Maven doesn't change that.

Comment: The public api is not supposed to be integrated in the jar file produced by gradle ?

Comment: No, it's not supposed to be.

Comment: So how do I retrieve the actual jar file in order to bundle it into my product ? In this case what is the difference between implement() and api() ? If I have to provide the jar file it's interface will be public anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to JB Nizet who put me in the right direction, I found a solution.
I just had to create a configuration first, then assign dependencies to this configuration in order to copy them:

```
configurations {
    deployerJars
}

dependencies {
    deployerJars group: 'org.n52.matlab', name: 'matlab-control', version: '5.0.0'
}

task copyToLib(type: Copy) {
    into "$buildDir/libs"
    from configurations.deployerJars
}
```